# Angular 4 Display different component under same route

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have two component `LoginComponentA` and `LoginComponentB`. They each should be accessed depending on a variable related with accessing portal. And they should be under **the same url**.

I tried to achieve it by:

```
{
    path: 'login',
    component: (() => {
        switch (AppSettings.loginPortal) {
            case 'portalA':
                return LoginComponentA;
            case 'portalB':
                return LoginComponentB;
        }
    })()
}
```

But I got errors on ng serve:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'appRoutes'.
Consider exporting the symbol (position 42:7 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppRoutingModule in /home/lis/apps/AZGIV/src/app/app-routing.module.ts
```

If I wrap the function after component like this:

```
export function getLoginComponent() {
    switch (AppSettings.loginPortal) {
            case 'portalA':
                return LoginComponentA;
            case 'portalB':
                return LoginComponentB;
    };
}
...
{
    path: 'login',
    component: getLoginComponent
}
```

I got errors:

```
Type '() => typeof LoginComponentA | typeof LoginComponentB' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'.
```

How can I fix the error? Or is there other way to display components conditionally under same route ?

I'm using Angular 4.2.4

Comment: Probably not the best solution, but can you route to a component that contains both of those components? Then you can display one with `ngIf` depending on the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a dummy container component in which you should use this condition.

for example

```
{
   path: 'login'
   component: LoginContainerComponent
}


@Component({
    template: `
    <app-login-component-a *ngIf="loginPortal === 'portalA'"></app-login-component-a>
    <app-login-component-b *ngIf="loginPortal === 'portalB'"></app-login-component-b>
    `

})
export class LoginContainerComponent {
   loginPortal: '';

   constructor() {
       this.loginPortal = AppSettings.loginPortal;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with matchers, so you can make multiple routing elements with the same route:

```js
const loginRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        matcher: (url: UrlSegment[]) => {
            if (url[0] === '/login' && useComponentA) {
                return { consumed: [url[0]] };
            }
            return null;
        },
        component: LoginComponentA
    },
    {
        matcher: (url: UrlSegment[]) => {
            if (url[0] === '/login' && useComponentB) {
                return { consumed: [url[0]] };
            }
            return null;
        },
        component: LoginComponentB
    },
];
```

Angular uses first-match routes.
So if you define a path, the first one to match will win, the second definition will never be reached.
But if you return null in a matcher, it tries the next definition.

Here's a more detailed explanation: https://medium.com/@lenseg1/loading-different-angular-modules-or-components-on-routes-with-same-path-2bb9ba4b6566